# putting Firebase asynchronous calls into a queue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, priority-queue, task-queue

I am using Firebase for Android.  I have a bunch of asynchronous calls that I need to start at the same time, but if I start them all, Android crashes.  Thus, I need to put them into a queue of some sort.  Here is the Firebase Java code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
       Task<Uri> currentTask = imageStorageRef[i].getDownloadUrl();

       // add tasks to a queue here rather than starting the addOnSuccessListener?
       // taskQueue.add(currentTask);

       // this is the asynchronous call which I cannot start too many of at the same time, or it will crash
       currentTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String profileImageUrlNew = uri.toString();
                MatchesObject obj = new MatchesObject(userIdFinal, nameFinal, profileImageUrlNew, cityStateFinal, convoIdFinal);
                resultsMatches.add(obj);
                mMatchesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
       });

}
```

What kind of queue should I use?  how do I tell when something exits from the queue?  how do I ensure that when space frees up in the queue, that I can add in the next asynchronous event?

I have read about BlockingQueue and AsyncQueue, but I don't get them yet.

Comment: Personally, I think you should file a bug report with the details of what you're trying to do, and the crash your seeing.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Are you trying to download images to show it in your `RecyclerView`? Why don't you use Glide in that case?

Comment: @ReazMurshed :  I have a bunch of firebase storage paths and I need to convert them into http urls, which I later use to download with glide.

Comment: @DougStevenson is this really a bug?  It seems like a hardware limitation, since I can do this for up to about 100, but it doesn't work for more than that.

Comment: I would still file a bug anyway, unless you can find some documentation the states the limits for what you're trying to do.